# NVidia X Server widnow doesn't show me perfomance or any other mode

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, xserver

after couple of months I wanted to play a game of CSGO on my laptop dual booting windows and linux. I haven't been using Win10 ever since I've switched to linux in January and I used to play CSGO on performance mode easily before. But now, maybe due to some driver update I can't see all options in nvidia x server settings like before. Bellow is the look of my nvidia x server window. Thanks in advance! [image] [image]

Comment: Is this screen shot from Windows or Ubuntu?

Comment: @David Ubuntu, kernel version 5.11.0-7620-generic

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution on [this forum thread](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/black-screen-after-install-of-nvidia-driver-ubuntu/109312), it worked out for my case.

Steps:

- Delete `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`
- Make sure nvidia-prime is installed by running

  ```
  sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-prime
  ```
- Use prime-select to switch to nvidia

  ```
  sudo prime-select nvidia
  ```
- Check for and remove stray blacklist files such as `/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf` and `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf`
- Regenerate the initrd

  ```
  sudo update-initramfs -u
  ```

And reboot